ShortcutManager crashes at last version of play services
Recently in my projects I updated Play Game Services Library from
  implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:19.0.0")

to
  implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:20.1.0")

Once I did it, some of my users started getting multiple repititive crashes:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.content.pm.ShortcutManager.getDynamicShortcuts()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.v2.appshortcuts.zze.zzb(zze.java:474)
       at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.v2.appshortcuts.zzd.run(zzd.java:474)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

This crash appears regardless of manufacturer, OS version or type of device.
I never invoke ShortcutManager in my code. The crash is happening in the first second of app usage.
How to beat it?
This crash appears only if applications deployes as instantapp version.

This problem was dissapeared since 20.1.1 version of dependency
